# Ways to ask for opinions over subjects/items/events

Tags: expression, colloquial

In english if I want to ask for someone's opinion of a movie or event I would ask

> What did you think of [*insert topic*]?

or I would ask

> How did you find the [*insert topic*]?

In German I was taught

> Wie hältst du von [*etwas*]?

I think I came across where people use **finden**; but I am not sure how to use it. Can someone share some common colloquial examples of how one can ask for opinions over any topic?

Comment: Z.B.: _`[etwas]` Wie denkst Du darüber?_, _Was ist Deine Meinung zu `[etwas]`?_, etc. Your question is quite broad. You should probably add more context, specific examples respectively.

Comment: _" I think I came across where people use `finden` but not sure how to use it."_ _Wie findest Du `[etwas]`?_ Simple like that.

Comment: Ich verstehe absolut nicht, wieso die Frage mit "too broad" markiert und abgewertet wurde.

Answer (score 3):

> Wie hältst du von [*etwas*]?

is wrong, but

> Was hältst du von [*etwas*]?

is fine when asking for an opinion.

> Wie findest du [*etwas*]?

is fine, too. It depends on the context, which is more appropriate, for example, I would prefer

> Wie findest du das Essen?
>
> Was hältst du von dem neuen Kollegen?

Certainly, more expressions are possible.

Comment: Especially with *finden*, if it not an ongoing thing, you would normally use the past form: *Wie fandest Du den Film?* (how did you like the movie?) - *Wie **findest** Du den Film?* is something you might ask the person you are watching it with on TV during the commercial break (or whisper it while watching it at the cinema).